# FFmpeg transcoding mpeg2 to H264 and compare frames

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-capture, codec, transcoding

I have the following mpeg2 source file:

> Stream #0:0[0x900]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002),
>   yuv420p(tv, top first), 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 4540 kb/s, 25
>   fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc

And transcoding it to H264 with the following command:

> ffmpeg -i source.mpg -vcodec h264_nvenc -r 25 -g 25 -acodec copy
>   -copyts -f mpegts  example1.mpg

After this I want to extract identical frames from the both video files:

> ffmpeg -y -ss 00:44:16 -i source.mpg -frames:v 1 source.png
>
> ffmpeg -y -ss 00:44:16 -i example1.mpg -frames:v 1 example1.png

But pictures(source.png and example1.png) are different. Please see the source.png:
[image]

And the example1.png
[image]

**How can I catch the same moment(frame) at the both video**?

Comment: Can you use frame-number instead of time? If so then you can extract 100th frame from both video like  `ffmpeg -i source.mpg -vf "select=gte(n\,100)" -vframes 1 source.png`

Comment: @danishansari thank you so much! This is exactly what is needed. Please add this as an answer and I will approve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of time, you can use frame number to extract frames from both videos. For example you can use following to command to get 100th frame from video:-

```
ffmpeg -i source.mpg -vf "select=gte(n\,100)" -vframes 1 source.png
```